# could not load inserted library: /usr/lib/libgenkit.dylib

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode4, dyld

I'm trying to run my universal app into device(iPad) but am getting this linker error

```
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
warning: Couldn't get real path for inserted library     /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.3   (8J2)/Symbols/usr/lib/libgenkit.dylib

warning: Couldn't get real path for inserted library   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.3 (8J2)/Symbols/usr/lib/libgenkit.dylib

target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-26364-38
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
[Switching to process 11779 thread 0x0]
[Switching to process 11779 thread 0x0]
dyld: could not load inserted library: /usr/lib/libgenkit.dylib
```

am using ShareKit,sqlcipher,  lexicontex,

anybody has idea ?!! please and thnx

Comment: No idea how ,,but when I stop running then opening the app on my iPad it works fine !!!! but that to figure out why?!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same problem, and finally reinstall xcode sovled it.
I think this is because I installed some software before. The suspicious is the one called "genieo"

Comment: updating to xcode 4.3 solved my problem .. !! and I did install that app before "genio"on my mac and then uninstalled it !! I dunno that might be the problem ...thnx for ur answer